# How to manage Azure APIM as Infrastructure as Code (IaC)?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

We recently started using APIM in Azure to host a few APIs available via a gateway. However, this is just 1 environment.

How does everyone handle APIM changes across multiple dev and production environments? SCM configuration that API provides acts as a repo but only for 1 Service.

Can different APIs be templatized across different APIM instances and environments?

How is everyone keeping copies of redundant policy files?

Comment: You could use this kit for example (https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit) and modify it to your needs. Then build a workflow/pipeline that gets triggered and does the actual deploy to APIM.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to define everything with bicep and manage the deployments to multiple environments via pipelines.

You can have one set of bicep scripts that define all common areas, like APIM Service, products/subscriptions, common named values, global policy, backends, etc. This would allow you to provision a new environment when need be and would allow you to have all the benefits of the source control.

And then you should have a different set of bicep scripts that are responsible for publishing individual api, ie swagger file, operational policies, which products the api belongs to, etc. You could create a common *publishing api* yaml template that would be referenced by APIs own pipelines

No APIM changes should be done directly via azure portal, but rather via CI/CD pipelines.